# "She wasn't sleeping eight hours"?

Tags: american-english, progressive-aspect

Take a look at [this](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/dr-christopher-winter/sleep_b_2084339.html) article from the *Huffington Post*. In it, there is this paragraph right here:

> Eight hours. This number is spoken like gospel in this country when it comes to sleep. "How much sleep do I need?" Eight hours. "How can I feel like the people in Old Navy ads?" Get eight hours. "Why did that Spanish nun ruin that fresco?" **She wasn't sleeping eight hours.**

"She didn't sleep eight hours" makes much more sense to me. Why in the world is the progressive used here?

Answer (score 4):

It means she was not in the habit of sleeping eight hours. You don’t want a completed past for that, as it was habitual.

Answer (score 1):

She wasn't sleeping eight hours. --->  She wasn't *regularly* sleeping eight hours.

Nuns don't - they get up very early to pray. Typically nuns get about 6.5 hours sleep.

Comment: I just have to ask:  how do you know how much sleep the "typical" nun gets?  Is there a difference between cloistered orders and others?

Comment: @deadrat - um... I suppose I should have researched it and given a source. It was more of a factoid than part of the grammar so I didn't think to do that. I know that these nuns and monks have very strict rules, I used to chat to a monk who did community gardening and he told me a bit about it. It sounded pretty gruelling.

Comment: No need for research.  The certainty and precision just struck me as amusing.  Is "gruelling" a general description or does it refer to their diet?  And please feel free to ignore me on this topic.